# Three JS GLTFLoader is faulty with vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, three.js, gltf

I have a glb model which I am loading into my Vue project via Three js. I have managed to import several other models for practice, but the one I actually want on my page will not load. I have tried playing around with different scaling, positions, background colors (since the object is mostly black), and camera angles but I am not able to get it in frame no matter what I do. I am able to see the model perfectly in any regular gltf view, but I cannot see it in my project, what am I doing wrong here?

Edit: As a side note, I also tried changing the scale in blender, but that did not change the result.

```
const loader = new GLTFLoader();

let me = this; // must refer to the instance in vue in order to be added to the scene, have tested this with other models

loader.load(
   'pantalla_ball_2.glb',
   function(gltf) {
      gltf.scene.traverse(function( node ) {
         if ( node.isMesh ) { node.castShadow = true; }
      });
      gltf.scene.scale.set(1,1,1) // Have tried several scales from 0.01 to 200

      me.scene.add(gltf.scene);
      console.log("added") // added is successfully called every time
   },
   function(xhr) {
      console.log(xhr);
   },
   function(err) {
      console.log(err); // no errors appear in console
   }
);
```

The object loading perfectly in 3d viewer below
[image: The object in 3d viewer]

Comment: Have you tried adding just "gltf" to your scene. Also I presume your scene has some light?

Comment: Added only gltf to the scene gives me an error "Object is not an Instance of THREE.Object3D", there is also ambient lighting in the scene.

Comment: Can you see your object added as a child to the scene object once loaded?

Comment: Yes, both the gray and black meshes appear as children of the scene after the gltfloader.load command

Comment: Add an axes helper at the same position as your object just to ensure your camera is pointing at the correct spot. You should see a line for each axis.

const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper( 50 );
scene.add( axesHelper );

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to JP4 for his helpful comments, the issue was the ambient lighting was not strong enough to illuminate the object sufficiently enough to be seen. The axis helpers showed me that the object was there thanks to the gaps in the axes.